# Elasticsearch query failure due to ordering of keys in json

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a query on elastic search with geo distance filter. My query works as:

```
{ 
 "filter": 
    { 
      "geo_distance": { 
         "center_point": { "lon": 77.2909989, "lat": 28.6854955 }, 
         "distance": "100m", 
         "order": "asc" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

However, if I change the ordering of keys in the "geo_distance" json object such as distance comes first and then center_points. The query fails.

```
 { 
 "filter": 
    { 
      "geo_distance": { 
         "distance": "100m", 
         "order": "asc", 
         "center_point": { "lon": 77.2909989, "lat": 28.6854955 }
    } 
  } 
}
```

The query fails with error -

> illegal latitude value [251.71875] for [geo_distance]

I believe ordering of keys should not have any impact.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: what is your elasticsearch version?

Comment: @notionquest it's 2.3.2